# How to active scan WiFi in Android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

From the Android document we know that `WiFiManager.startScan()` invoke a **passive** WiFi scan. It usually takes more time than an **active scan**. As a result, I would like to invoke an **active scan** using the method below.

In the previous **WiFiManager.java** there is a hidden method called `startScanActive`. We cannot call it directly, but we can invoke it via java reflection. [What does @hide mean in the Android source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)

However, this method disappeared in the Android 4.3+. Then, how to begin an active WiFi scan in Android 4.3+?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17056643/1137118 explains `@hide`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Active Scan is not possible and so is removed from the later API levels.

It is a device and/or OS version dependent setting. On the Nexus One for example it takes roughly a second to scan whereas on the G1 it takes significantly longer (or get fresh results after a few scans).

Moreover, Android does passive scans, it listens for beacons. Doing an active scan can create a lot of congestion on the network by sending out probe requests and waiting for probe responses.

Refer: [android-wifi-active-scans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880453/android-wifi-active-scans) and [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan()).

Comment: Are you sure Android does passive scans? My HTC One M8 sends Probe Requests periodically, even when WiFi is turned off (but "scanning always available" option is enabled).

Answer (score -1):

Then you can use the following in your activity class:

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

Comment: Bwahahaha. You'd expect a `Guru` to provide a relevant answer.